# How can I speed up this progress bar?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to increase the speed of the progress bar for the code below, or remove the animation so it loads straight away.

```
var match_rate = <?php echo $match_rate; ?>; 
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= match_rate) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width += 0.1; //change the increment value to 0.1 instead of 1
      width = Math.round(width * 10) / 10; // round to nearest decimal
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should be using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Also, a loop interval of `1ms` is excessive: that's 1,000Hz - whereas for 60fps (i.e. 60Hz) you only need an interval of 16.6ms.

Comment: `elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';` <-- Consider using `textContent` or `innerText` instead.

Comment: _"remove the animation so it loads straight away."_ - What problems are you having removing the poll loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smooth transition effect can be achieved with the help of CSS transition. Checkout the code below:

```js
var match_rate = 75;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var bar = document.getElementById("myBar");
  bar.style.width = match_rate + "%";
  bar.textContent = bar.style.width;
});
```

```css
#myBarContainer {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#myBar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* For faster transition effect reduce transition time here */
  transition: width 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBarContainer">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good start, but if you completely remove the frame( ) method it will break other code on the page that calls it.  OP did not share that information, but we can assume that the method is called when some process updates or completes.